# Express $\frac{6}{x+3}x$ as a sum of partial fractions and find the integral where $5$ is at the top and $1$ is at the bottom?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Please correct me if I have gone wrong anywhere, once the integral has been found through partial fractions how would you solve it using Simpson’s rule with $4$ strips and working to $3$ decimal places, calculating an approximate value, and determining the error of approximation?
$$
\frac{6}{x(x+3)}=\frac{A}{x+3} + \frac{B}{x}
$$

Adding the separate terms together
\begin{align*}
\frac{Ax(x+3)}{x+3} + \frac{Bx(x+3)}{x}\\
A(x+3)+\frac{Bx}{x(x+3)}\\
6=A(x+3)+Bx\\
\end{align*}
Let $x=0$
\begin{align*}
6&=A(0+3)+B(0)\\
\frac63&=A\\
A&=2\\
\end{align*}
Let $x=-3$ for $B$
\begin{align}
6&=A(-3+3)+B(-3)\\
\frac{6}{-3}&=B\\
B&=-2
\end{align}
Partial fraction answer
$$
\frac{-2}{x}+3+\frac{2}{x}
$$
Now using the previous answer by integration: where $5$ is at the top and 1 is at the bottom
\begin{align}
\int \frac2x -\frac2x+3 \, dx\\
[2\ln(x)-2\ln(x+3)]\\
[(2\ln(5)-2\ln(4))-(2\ln(1)-2\ln(1+3))]
\end{align}

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you for the extra resources, I am still trying to get around this site. In regards to the question have I got it right or do i need to continue

Comment: Your coefficients are reversed:  your second and third lines should be $$ \frac{Ax}{x(x+3)} \ + \  \frac{B (x+3)}{x(x+3)} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{Ax \ + \ B(x+3)}{x(x+3)} \ \ . $$  The numbers $ \ 2 \ $ and $ \ -2 \ $ are correct, but they will be on the wrong logarithmic terms.

Comment: @boojum So would that leave my answer unaffected apart from A=-2 and B=2?

Comment: The anti-derivative at the end is correct.  You will have your coefficients swapped relative to the given answer.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to know what to do, but have difficulty writing it out.

---

We want to find an $A$ and $B$ that makes:$$\dfrac 6{x(x+3)}=\dfrac A{x+3} + \dfrac B x$$

Multiplying both sides by $x(x+3)$, we obtain: $$\begin{align}6&=Ax+B(x+3)\\[1ex]&=(A+B)x+3B\end{align}$$

Thus we need $A+B=0$ and $3B=6$.

That is : $B=2, A=-2$

Therefore $$\begin{align}\int \dfrac{6}{x(x+3)}\mathrm d x&=\int\dfrac{-2}{x+3}+\dfrac{2}{x}\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=-2\ln(x+3)+2\ln(x)+C\\[3ex]\int_1^5\dfrac{6}{x(x+3)}\mathrm d x &=[-2\ln(8)+2\ln(4)]+[2\ln(5)-2\ln(1)]\\[1ex]&=2(\ln 5-\ln 2)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much yeah I get so mixed up on the partial fractions but seem to fix my error as a previous commenter pointed out